# Jade - Using --watch doesn't trigger refresh from includes

Tags: include, pug, watch, templating

I have a simple project I am trying to work with.

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  include ./inc/head.jade

body
  include ./inc/various.jade
  include ./inc/types.jade
  include ./inc/of.jade
  include ./inc/things.jade
```

using this commmand to watch 
    jade -w index.jade

I would expect any change to 'things.jade' would trigger a refresh to 'index.jade'. It does not. What am I missing? I don't want to call the watch command each time I need a refresh on index.jade.

Desired workflow:

```
save change in things.jade > triggers refresh to index.jade
```

Current problem:

```
save change in things.jade > switch to terminal > control+c to 
kill the watch on index.jade > jade -w index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen your question now, I hope you got it fixed.
It seems you require '[liveReload](http://livereload.com)' to watch for changes when you save a file then to reload your browser.

If you are using a task runner for example 'gulp' is would strongly recommend using '[gulp-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect)' It runs a local web server using 'LiveReload'

Using this technique you will not have to call the watch command each time you need a refresh on index.jade